# Jenkins declarative pipeline: git --fetch tags is taking lot of time

Tags: git, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am using Jenkins multibranch pipeline with options as shown in the below screenshot

[image]

```
Git version: git version 2.28.0.windows.1
```

During pipeline execution below command is taking a lot of time.

git fetch --tags --force --progress -- origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10

I need tags as I am using git --describe tags command in my pipeline which fails if I do not enable "Fetch tags" option

Did anyone face this issue earlier or is this related to git version

Comment: Somewhat related; We have seen a performance difference between checkout via SSH; vs HTTPS (different network routes/proxy hoops) on the same repo. Secondly; is this difference only on Jenkins and/or on a new branch/job?

Comment: Yes, this is observed on Jenkins